# Convert the lead created in a screen flow to an opportunity automatically

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, opportunity, lead-conversion

I have lightning flow which creates a new Lead record. Now my requirement is that, as soon as my lead gets created its has to be automatically converted to an opportunity.

I understand, that I can embed a lightning component and call a controller code to perform this. But my question is that is there any way to implement this without the use of code and just by the flow itself?

Comment: why are you even creating lead if you are not using it and converting it by following a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a lead is converted to a contact and opportunity there are several different things that happen. [Info Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_leads_what_happens_when.htm&type=5) When you use flow automation, you miss out on some of the more technical parts of it.

Depending on your requirements, it might be fine to create the flow automation that create the records you need and doesn't do some of the more technical things. This is what I've done for years.

I only started using apex when I needed to sync my contacts and leads with Pardot, because they really want your lead to be converted when you create a contact, since the Pardot prospects can only sync with one sf record.